# Tradingview Pine scripts giving resolution error for line draw function

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

```
//@version=4

study(shorttitle="try", title="line", overlay=true, resolution="")

line.new(x1=bar_index[10], y1=close[10], x2=bar_index, y2=close)
```

I want to draw a simple line in trading view chart using pine scripts.
I am getting resolution error. Am I missing anything?

Error:
line 5: The 'resolution' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects.
Script 'crcheck' has been saved

Comment: If you're the one who asked the same question in Pine Script chat, don't ask the same question in multiple forums. You risk getting different volunteers helping you concurrently.

Comment: It seems the "label" or "line" function is causing the problem mainly. It's a bug. Since the feature is officially implemented in the late 2020 and it is quite new, I hope this should be fixed in near future.

Answer (score 5):

Remove

```
, resolution=""
```

then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Wording is obscure because of space constraints, but it means you're using stuff that can't be calculated/rendered on other TFs. Doesn't mean it's impossible to code in Pine; you will most often be able to code it using `security()`; just means it can't be handled with the `resolution` method, whose purpose is to provide a simple way to provide MTF functionality for simple scripts. It does not deprecate `security()`.